# How do I get the updated rows id when using on duplicate update in a inserting multiple rows query?

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables, Person(id, name, phone, partner), Partner(id, personA, personB). Person table has unique key (name, phone) and the id is auto-incremented.

I have an insert query that insert multiple rows which will first check if name or phone is the same, then decide whether update the partner fields or do a normal inert.

```
INSERT INTO Table1(name, phone, partner) 
VALUES ("name1", "phone1", "partner1"), ("name2", "phone2", "partner2")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE partner = VALUES(partner);
```

So the point is, every time I execute this query, it will possibly update or insert multiple rows.

Is there a way that I can get those updated row's ids so that I can insert the ids to the Partner table? I don't need to update the Partner table, just insert.

Following question will be, I can use row_count before and after the query been executed to get how many rows been inserted and their id's range. But is there any better way to work around with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check this one `INSERT INTO persons (firstname,lastname) VALUES ('John','Doe');
SET @partner = LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Comment: @BloodyLogic I know, but what if the query inserts multiple rows.
So the purpose of this question is because I have a bunch of queries like what you just posted and I am trying to group them all together to make it more efficient.

Comment: As it is, your query is inserting one record (or 0 if duplicate key happens), not multiple rows. I think that you would need to give more details on what you are trying to achieve and the issue that you are getting.

Comment: @GMB This is just an example query. The real one will have more than two values. I am asking if it's possible to get those rows that been updated.